# spark scala merge multi rdd by key

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have got multi rdds

`genderRDD`

```
(1713926427,{gender={f=3327, m=1945, unknown=897}})
```

And

`actionRDD`

```
(1713926427,{actionType={repost=2927, comment=2345, like=897}})
```

And

`deviceRDD`

```
(1713926427,{deviceType={iphone=2999, android=12321}})
```

They are of the format `RDD(id, HashMap[String, HashMap[String, Integer]])`

I want to merge the two rdds by id which should generate:

```
(1713926427,{gender={f=3327, m=1945, unknown=897},actionType={repost=2927, comment=2345, like=897},device={iphone=2999, android=12321}})
```

So that I can store it to the database. How to do that typically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that `{deviceType={iphone=2999, android=12321}}` represents a `Map[String, Map[String, Int]]`, in that case - you should simply use `join`s and then some simple mapping to "flatten" the result:

```
// some sample data:
val rdd1 = sc.parallelize(Seq((1713926427, Map("gender" -> Map("f" -> 3327, "m" ->1945, "unknown" -> 897)))))
val rdd2 = sc.parallelize(Seq((1713926427, Map("actionType" -> Map("repost" -> 2927, "comment" -> 2345, "like" -> 897)))))
val rdd3 = sc.parallelize(Seq((1713926427, Map("deviceType" -> Map("iphone" -> 2999, "android" -> 12321)))))

// join all three RDDs and map to flatten the value:
val result = rdd1
  .join(rdd2)
  .join(rdd3)
  .map { case (id, ((gender, action), device)) => (id, (gender ++ action ++ device)) }

// result has type RDD[(Int, Map[String, Map[String, Int]])]
result.foreach(println)
// prints:
// (1713926427,Map(gender -> Map(f -> 3327, m -> 1945, unknown -> 897), actionType -> Map(repost -> 2927, comment -> 2345, like -> 897), deviceType -> Map(iphone -> 2999, android -> 12321)))
```